# Send mail with Table formatting just like flipkart invoice mail using smtp in csharp

Tags: c#, email, formatting

I am looking for the real mail facility using csharp. the mail is send with an attachment and we can able to send mail to multiple people. and somewhat about formatting how to send tables witch is display in the table format

Comment: Okay cool, what is the question, what is the problem, what have you tried and what didn't work, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: OK thank you sir for explaining  format of Question i will take care of it from next time.....

Answer (score 0):

Formatting can be Done By using an HTML Code we can include html code in CSharp directly for better understanding check the following code

```html
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("Form@mail.com");
            mail.To.Add(txt_to.Text);
            mail.Subject = txt_subject.Text;
            mail.Body = txt_body.Text;
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new 
          System.Net.Mail.Attachment(lbl_attach.Text);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);



           mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
              string htmlBody;

              htmlBody = "Your html Design is here";
            //do the design as per requirements
              mail.Body = htmlBody;


            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("form@gmail.com", "*****");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    
        }
```